# midpoint convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, lebesgue-measure

We know every convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue measurable.
Can we prove every midpoint convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue measurable?

We say a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is midpoint convex if whenever
$x,y\in S,$ then $\frac{x+y}{2}\in S.$

As PhoemueX points out, there exist a midpoint convex set which is not Lebesgue measurable if we assume the axiom of choice.

Comment: You might try the $\Bbb{Q}$ span of a subset of a Hamel basis (remove one element of the basis) for $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks a lot.